# Strange windows window panel

Tags: windows, window, panel

I'm developing an application for the game window but I encounter a strange issue. About 5% of users have different top window panels of the game. In the attachment, you can see the normal window panel and Incorrect (different) version. Every user uses Windows 10 and has the same version of the game application. I'm not sure but on the right side of the incorrect window panel, there is some old-styled leftover (kind of) off minimize/fullscreen/exit buttons. Does anyone know what may cause this strange problem? Maybe they need to change some windows settings, so their game window will look like a Normal window panel?

[Window panel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9caa.png)

Comment: I think that's the result of an increased scale value in Windows Display settings (scale and layout combo). Something like 125%, while default is 100%.

Comment: Wow, exactly that was an issue. Thank you very much for your help!